# what is the ideal way to use connection pooling in my scenario

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am new to connection pooling i need suggestions in below scenario :

I have two projects which have hibernate connection pooling with spring.

Now i have a scenario where i have to create a new project which redirects the requests.
In the new project i have to authenticate the request by connecting to database, this will be the ONLY call to database in the whole project.

I was asked to go for hibernate which i feel is not required..as there is only one query to database , and is it not a good way to use JDBC connection for authenticating the request and connection pooling mechanisms available with jdbc to make sure connections are pooled ?

What is the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a connection pool library such as *boneCP*. It can be used both from Hibernate and directly;
2. your advisors may have a point after all: software projects have a tendency to acquire new features over time. If you start with Hibernate, there will be less code to rewrite once the pain threshold of manual JDBC is exceeded.